# Issues with Backtesting.py

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, back-testing

I've been backtesting a strategy for a lot of assets with the same parameters using Backtesting.py.
For this reason I created a loop "for". In each iterarion of the loop, I run the backtest with an asset whoose OHLC data were taken from a Excel file. The issue is that for some assets, the backtest is resulting in 0 trades done.
When I run the same strategy, with the same parameters from Python iteractive prmpt, the result makes sense with a number of trades compatible with the date from where I started the backtest!
I don't know what happening! Basically, I make a loop for and in each iteration I run the backtest with a specific asset with the same parameters for all assets. In my case, I have OHLC data from 121 asset, so the backtest is done 121 times in a row.
Please, anyine may help me to solve this issue! The code is below:

def testa_model (dire: str, plan: str, startDate: str, **kwargs):
Files = [x for x in listdir(dire) if x.upper().endswith(".XLSX")]
for file in tqdm(Files):
flData = join(dire, file)
asset = file.upper().replace('.XLSX','')
DADO = pd.read_excel(flData, sheet_name=0,
parse_dates=True, index_col="Data", decimal=",")
DADO = DADO.sort_index()
DADO = DADO[DADO.index > startDate]
DataInicial =f"{DADO.index[0]:%d/%m/%Y}"
DADO = DADO.dropna(axis=0)
RSI2.v_ifrLow = kwargs['IFR']
RSI2.max = kwargs['MAX']
RSI2.ndays = kwargs['DAYS']
RSI2.Loss = kwargs['LOSS']
RSI2.Type = kwargs['TIPO']
RSI2.pATR = kwargs['ATR']
Param = f"IFR={kwargs['IFR']} MAX={kwargs['MAX']} DAYS={kwargs['DAYS']} " 

f"LOSS={kwargs['LOSS']} ATR={kwargs['ATR']}"
bt = Backtest(DADO, RSI2, cash=50000, commission=0.0, trade_on_close=True)
stats = bt.run()
T = stats._trades

Payoff = T[T['PnL']>0]['PnL'].mean() / abs(T[T['PnL']<0]['PnL'].mean())
initialCash = stats['Equity Final [$]']/(1+stats['Return [%]']/100)
bestOp = initialCash*(1+(stats['Best Trade [%]']/100))
worstOp = initialCash*(1+(stats['Worst Trade [%]']/100))
nOpGain = round(stats['Win Rate [%]']/100*stats['# Trades'])
nOpLoss = stats['# Trades'] - nOpGain
listAppend = [
asset,
stats['Profit Factor'],
stats['Win Rate [%]'],
Payoff,
stats['Sharpe Ratio'],
stats['# Trades'],
bestOp,
worstOp,
stats['Avg. Trade Duration'],
stats['Equity Final [$]'],
stats['Equity Peak [$]'],
stats['Return [%]'],
nOpGain,
nOpLoss,
stats['Max. Drawdown [%]'],
stats['Avg. Drawdown [%]'],
Param,
DataInicial
]
otim = pd.read_excel(plan)
otim.loc[len(otim)] = listAppend
otim.to_excel(plan,index=False)

I've tried delete objects at the end of loop and import again in the beggining, I've tried to add sleep(5) before backtest